# python) how to divide a python 1D list to constant number of random size python lists(2D)

Tags: python, list

I have a 1D list and I want to divide it into 4 "chunks" with each "chunk" being a random size within a certain range.

example

```
a_list = [[2, 0], [7], [4, 3], [1, 5, 6]]
```

I want to change this 2D list into a 1D list and then regroup a random number of values(range 0 to length of 1D list) inside the 1D list into 4 groups.

Comment: So first you want to have `[2, 0, 7, 4, 3, 1, 5, 6]` and then something like `[[2, 0, 7], [4], [3, 1], [5, 6]]`?

Comment: yes but I want to differ the size of the subgroups each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flatten the list you can use `itertools.chain`. Then you have to have to find some random indexes where you can split the list. You can use `random.sample` for that.

```
from itertools import chain
import random

a_list = [[2, 0], [7], [4, 3], [1, 5, 6]]
number_of_chunks = 4

# flatten the list
data = list(chain.from_iterable(a_list))
print(data)

# get indexes where to split the list
indexes = sorted(random.sample(list(range(1, len(data))), number_of chunks-1))
print(indexes)
# add start end end of the list indexes
indexes = [0] + indexes + [None]
print(indexes)

# with zip we get pairs of start and end points for the chunks
# and then create the chunks in a list comprehension
result = [data[s:e] for s, e in zip(indexes, indexes[1:])]
print(result)
```

Due to the random part you'll get answers like `[[2, 0], [7], [4, 3, 1], [5, 6]]`, `[[2, 0, 7], [4, 3], [1, 5], [6]]` or `[[2], [0, 7], [4, 3, 1, 5], [6]]`.

---

To answer the questions from the comment:

Yes, `random.sample` is uniform.

If you want to have possible duplicate split points - leading to an empty sublist - you have to use an other approach than using `sample`. Create your indexes with

```
indexes = sorted([random.randint(1, len(data) - 1) for _ in range(number_of_chunks - 1)])
```

And don't forget to add a `0` at the beginning and `None` at the end of this index list.

This could produce results like `[[2, 0, 7, 4, 3, 1, 5], [], [], [6]]`

Comment: First of all, I give you my thanks for taking your time to answer my question! I have two additional questions. First, I also need a case where there would be an empty sublist inside the list. Would this be possible with this code? Second, am I correct in assuming that the probability of the random.sample is uniform?

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. If this is what you want, could you consider to upvote/accept it?

Comment: Thanks your answer was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Using something like `zip(indexes, indexes[1:])` is a nice way to iter pairwise over a list.